# Erlang Nodes See Each Other Only After Ping

Tags: macos, erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

I am running some erlang code on a Mac OSX, and I have this weird issue. My application is a multi node app where I have a single instance of a server that is shared between nodes (global).

The code works perfectly, except for one annoying thing: the different erlang nodes (I am running each node on a different terminal window) can only communicate with each other after ping!

So if on terminalA I am starting the server, and on terminalB I am running

```
erl>global:registered_names().
```

terminalB will return an empty list, unless, before starting the server on terminalA, I have ran a ping (from either one of the terminals).

For example, if I do this on either terminals before starting the server:

```
erl>net_adm:ping("terminalB").
```

then I start the server and from the second terminal I list the processes:

```
erl>global:registered_names().
```

This time I WILL see the registered process from the second terminal.

Is it possible that the mere net_adm:ping call does some kind of work (like DNS resolving or something like that) that allows the communication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The nodes in a distributed Erlang system are loosely connected. The
>   first time the name of another node is used, for example if
>   spawn(Node,M,F,A) or net_adm:ping(Node) is called, a connection
>   attempt to that node will be made.

I find this in this link: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#id85336

I think you should read this article.